# jquery getJson method is not working in html

Tags: java, html, xml, json, jsonpath

getJSON("sample.json") is not working when invoking from html in D:"  { "name" : "blah" } getJSON("D:/data/sample_json.json",fun

Comment: Why do you think we can do anything with the details you've given us?

Comment: Please give more information

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to request JSON by using a path to a file on your system. Its hard to say if this is the only thing you'll need to change though.

Comment: Are you sure that we cannot load a json file from local system?

Comment: Yes, the browser will prevent an AJAX call from trying to read a file on your system for security reasons.  You'll need to run a local web server and access it that way.